# What are the PostGIS Raster Constraints used for?

Tags: postgis, raster, spatial-index

My question is quite basic, but I have not found a simple explanation of why raster constraints are useful.

I have worked with rasters in PostGIS for a while but only recently I realized that I do not understand what the raster constraints are for. I understand that the constraints may provide some general information about the rasters in a specific table, but I have never accessed the constraints directly and am wondering how they are used internally in PostGIS.

My motivation for asking this question is that I have a single raster column with rasters of different sizes, extents and SRIDs and so the raster constraints are not very well bounded. If the raster constraints are used for indexing this might have implications on performance of the raster table in terms of speed when reading from the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raster constraints are used to ensure that all rasters have the same SRID, pixel dimensions, pixel types and alignments, as you can see from [RT_AddRasterConstraints docs](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_AddRasterConstraints.html). These are important if you want to do intersections, resampling, unions, reprojections, or vector-raster overlays, etc, as I'm sure you know.

I was surprised that you could add an index on a column with different SRIDs -- you can with vector also. It would seem that index construction makes no reference to the SRID and only uses the bounding boxes of the underlying geometries during construction, regardless of SRID. This seems strange as if you then try and do any queries against a table with mixed SRIDs in, you will get an `Operation on Mixed SRID geometries` error.

An illustration with some geometries, which use the same Postgres GIST index.

```
create table test(id serial, geom geometry);
insert into test (geom) select st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,0),4326);
insert into test (geom) select st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,0),27700);
create index ix_spatial_test on test using gist(geom);
select st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom) from test a, test b where a.id!=b.id;
```

returns `ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries`

Whereas, if you explicitly state the SRID in the where clause, eg,

```
select id from test 
where st_intersects(st_setsrid(st_expand(st_makepoint(0,0),1),4326),geom) 
and st_srid(geom)=4326;
```

the query returns 1, as you would expect.

I think that mixing rasters of different SRIDs in one column is generally to be avoided, but do not think it will have much impact on performance or index creation, other than making queries more awkward, due to having to either reproject geometries with ST_Transform or only request those matching a certain SRID.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes sense to me, but does that mean that the raster constraints are not a requirement, but rather a way of self-imposing constraints on a table? I see the usefulness if one tries to have only one "type" of raster in a table (with specific srid etc), but if I understand your answer correctly, these constraints are voluntary, so I can leave them away if I keep track of srids etc in another way? i.e. no part of PostGIS raster relies on them...?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes. Voluntary, but a very good idea.